# What is the best way for very long text or string in Android?

Tags: android, sql, textview, viewflipper, longtext

I'm going to develop a eBook type android application, as per as my knowledge I'm trying to do this task like that,
there are only 2 activity, first Activity has a `ListView` with 100 items which are index of book, and second activity has a `ViewFlipper` with 100 child(`LinearLayout`), every child has a `ScrollView` with a `CustomTextView` in every `CustomTextView` has average 2 pages text, I kept those text in `string.xml` and show those text in `CustomTextView`, when press on item of `ListView` it will go desired child of `ViewFlipper`(if I press item 0 it will go child 0, 1-1, 2-2, n-n), it's working without any error, but after adding 50 pages text in 25 child, application getting slow(app size about 5MB).

My questions are:

1. Is there any better way to do this / to view those long text?
2. Where should kept those text, in `string.xml` or in SQLite database ?

Answer (score 0):

1.You should load Strings into your `CustomTextView` when user gets to there not before

2.based on John Leehey answers

> I don't think the strings.xml has a limit, so it would be best to
>   store your longest strings in there. That's really the only
>   Android-designated place to store strings, so if you want to really
>   use a different storage mechanism, you'll have to load the string from
>   a file or database.

Comment: is there any better way than ViewFlipper?, my application getting slow, i didn't get the solution :(

Comment: you use a textview inside scrollview when users reach the end of scrollview load more texts inside textview @ConfusedMan0